# Add linearLayout elements programmatically in activity Extends Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How should I add linearLayout elements programmatically in activity Extends Fragment?

I tried to add views but it only works if activity extends Activity. Is there any other way to make it work in activity extends Fragment?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_screen, container, false);
LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.my_root);
LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(this);
a.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
a.addView(view1);
a.addView(view2);
a.addView(view3);
myRoot.addView(a);
return v;
}
```

There is an error in.

```
LinearLayout a = new LinearLayout(this);
```

in (this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write getActivity() in place of 'this'
Try this once maybe it will help you

Thanks..

Comment: it removes the error . can you please tell me the differrence?? and how can i make a number of buttons and add them dynamically
thanks in advance

Comment: 'this' returns an activity object if you use it inside an activity but here you want an activity object in fragment.. and you want an activity object ..

Comment: LinearLayout row2 = new LinearLayout(this);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("txt for btn");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
layoutParams.setMargins(5, 3, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
row2.addView(btn);